# android have 8000 contacts render in Application

Tags: android, android-contacts

Application need to read the phonebook contacts and show it to the user, have more than 8000 contacts on the phone. 
Problem is it stuck for very long time while rendering all contacts on the screen.

Please suggest best way to accomplish this task. thanks

Main Method:

```
 Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
LogUtils.d("@@@ cursorCount" + contactsCursor.getCount());
contacts = new ArrayList<ImportContactModel>();
importContactList = new ArrayList<ImportContactModel>();
showProgressDialog();
asyncLoader = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        fetchContacts();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // create an array of Strings, that will be put to our
        // ListActivity
        adapter = new ImportContactArrayAdapter(
                ImportContactSelection.this, contacts);
        contactList.setAdapter(adapter);
        contactList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        initSearch();
        dismissProgressDialog();
    };

}.execute();
```

Class to get Data:

```
 public void fetchContacts() {

String phoneNumber = null;
String email = null;

Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
String PROFILE_PIC = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI;

Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

Uri EMAIL_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
String EMAIL_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
String EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
        null);

// Loop for every contact in the phone
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ImportContactModel tempContact = new ImportContactModel();
        String contact_id = cursor
                .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
        String image_uri = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(PROFILE_PIC));
        int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

        if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

            tempContact.setId(contact_id);
            if (image_uri != null)
                tempContact.setProfilePic(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(PROFILE_PIC)));
            else
                tempContact.setProfilePic("");
            tempContact.setContactName(name);
            // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
            Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                    PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { contact_id }, null);

            // Get All Phone Numbers
            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                tempContact.setContactNo(phoneNumber);
                break;
            }
            phoneCursor.close();

            Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(
                    EMAIL_CONTENT_URI, null, EMAIL_CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { contact_id }, null);
            while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contactId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(EMAIL_CONTACT_ID));
                email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
                tempContact.setEmail(email);
                break;
            }
            emailCursor.close();
            contacts.add(tempContact);
        }
    }
}
```

}
Adapter Class

```
   public class ImportContactArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImportContactModel> {

  private final List<ImportContactModel> list;
  private final Activity context;
  private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

  public ImportContactArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<ImportContactModel> list) {
super(context, R.layout.item_task_contact_select, list);
this.context = context;
this.list = list;
this.mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
 }

 static class ViewHolder {
protected ImageView profilePic;
protected TextView contactName;
protected TextView contactNo;
protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = null;
  if (convertView == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
  view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_task_contact_select, null);
  final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
  //viewHolder.profilePic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_import_profilePic);
  viewHolder.contactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
  viewHolder.contactNo = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tag_text_1);
  viewHolder.contactNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  viewHolder.contactNo.setTextSize(11);
  viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.select_checkbox);
  viewHolder.checkbox.setClickable(true);
  viewHolder.checkbox
      .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
            ImportContactModel element = (ImportContactModel) viewHolder.checkbox
              .getTag();
          element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

        }
      });
  view.setTag(viewHolder);
  viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
} else {
  view = convertView;
  ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
}
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
ImageView avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
ImageView avatarBorder = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar_overlay);
ProgressBar avatarProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar_progress);

if(!list.get(position).equals(""))
//holder.profilePic.setImageURI(Uri.parse(list.get(position).getProfilePic()));
mImageLoader.displayImage(list.get(position).getProfilePic(), avatar, new    AvatarsImageLoadingListener(avatarProgress, avatarBorder, R.drawable.bg_nophoto));
holder.contactName.setText(list.get(position).getContactName());
holder.contactNo.setText(list.get(position).getContactNo());
holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
return view;
   }

 public ArrayList<ImportContactModel> getCheckList(){
  ArrayList<ImportContactModel> tempList = new ArrayList<ImportContactModel>();
  for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
      if(list.get(i).isSelected()){
          tempList.add(list.get(i));
          LogUtils.d(""+list.get(i).getContactName());
      }
  }

  return tempList;
 }


}
```

So it just shows Loading screen for huge amount of time..

Comment: What have you tried so far? If your code is working, but slowly, may I suggest CodeReview?

Comment: how can u render 8000 contacts on a screen?

Comment: I already kept in Background thread, but loading screens for huge amount of time

Comment: @eldjon - Client phone has 8000 contacts on phone and when my App reads that contact it, takes a lot of time to render the custom list view of contacts

Comment: technically speaking android renders only the visible contacts on the screen which lets say around 10. so rendering shouldnt be catastrophic. can you post the custom list and its adapter, if any?

Comment: Do one thing. Show first 100/500 contacts on load. And start a thread to load other contacts and add to adapter.

Comment: @pankajkumar - Can you please tell me how can i query Contacts Adapter for less records..

Comment: @eldjon - Please look at code i have posted

Comment: Move to code from answer to appropriate place. Then find the performance bottleneck. Check which part takes most of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to fetch all contacts to display them. AsyncTask has `publishProgress` method. I'm not experienced with `Cursor` class, since I prefer ORM for that, so I'll write in pseudo code, you'll have to adapt it yourself.

```
//in AsyncTask
protected Void doInBackground(params){
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        contactInfo = createContact(currentCursorValue);
        publishProgress(contactInfo);
    }
}
onProgressUpdate(contactInfo){
    if(adapter==null){
        //first time adapter setup
    }
    adapter.add(contactInfo);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This way, every time you pull a record from Db, you publish it, and items are added continuously. User won't notice any delay, unless he tries searching for not yet existing items, or you want to implement that big pop up letter for fast scroll. Still, above code is not very effective, since publishing the progress every .001 second or so, is not very smart, so you can either publish every 20 results, or publish them every second, up to you.